# SSL certificate for www. and non-www domain

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

What SSL certificate should I buy to get my domain work?
I use `nginx` web server and want that all users requests go to `https`.

```
http://example.com -> https://example.com
http://www.example.com -> https://example.com
https://example.com -> https://example.com
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com
```

Do I have to buy 2 certificates for both domains `example.com` and `www.example.com`?
Or may I buy only one certificate with `subdomain` support?
What does `SAN` mean in SSL-certificates and how can it help me?

What `nginx` config do I need to get desire redirection?

Thanks.

Comment: The OP was asking about what kind of certificate to buy, not how to install the certificate.

Comment: Mohammad, did you read any of the answers to that question?  Four out of five of them deal with how to buy a certificate that supports what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

I think some certificates now support the `www` and `non-www` as a single certificate, without buying the whole subdomains support, it would be cheaper than the subdomain one, contact whichever provider you are considering and ask them if they support the `www` subdomain of the domain or not.